Spotfire- On Demand Data Based on Added Columns
I have an On-Demand table (For simplicity, let's call this OD-Table1) that stores various data columns, however, I had to add columns from another table (Let's call this Table2) to OD-Table1 because OD-Table1 is a separate database from Table2 and I cannot query them in the same query together. Table2 has values for "parts" of the OD-Table1. For a visual reference, here you go: 
Here's my issue- I really would like my On-Demand setting to use 2 limitations which would be a location code (sourced from OD-Table1) and a "part" code (only located in Table2). OD-Table1 only can handle the location code, but I need to filter by the part code as well. Because I added columns to the OD-Table1, I am unable to select the part column in the On-Demand Settings. Is there any way to work around this to only show that part's data from OD-Table1? Or could I somehow limit my visualizations and the data brought in from OD-Table1 by this part code based on user selection?
Appreciate the help very much!
Edit: I've found somewhat of a way to work around the issue, but it's not working quite right. In my custom query for OD-Table1, I have created a parameter "p" for my location, a parameter "x" for a starting depth, and a parameter "y" that represents an ending depth. In the text above, I mentioned a "part" code and each part has a start and end depth. OD-Table1 has depths and I figured that I might try to instead summon data based on depth boundaries, rather than a part code. Please make note that each part within a location will have it's own start and ending depth and there could be multiple parts of a location. This kind of works, but I have a problem summoning multiple locations to make comparisons. It can load one location perfectly, but any more causes an error code. Here's my custom query:
select * from OD-Table1.data where (location in (?p) and measured_depth>= (?x) and measured_depth<= (?y))

Here's a visual example of a couple of locations and their variables:

All parameters are of data type double and are being brought in as arrays. The code is verified to function.
